# Folland real analysis theorem 6.8

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces

On the theorem 6.8, from the real analysis by Folland, it says that simple functions are dense in $L^\infty$. Is this true? For example, a constant function, which never decays belongs to the $L^\infty$ but I cannot see how to approximate this with the simple functions. Also, I found from here ([http://math.stanford.edu/~ryzhik/STANFORD/STANF205-16/205_hw3_sol.pdf](http://math.stanford.edu/%7Eryzhik/STANFORD/STANF205-16/205_hw3_sol.pdf)) that simple functions are not dense in $L[0,1]$. Is this because of the inconsistency of the definition of the simple function? I noticed some require finite measure support.

Comment: if $C$ is your constant, then $f(x) = C 1_{X} \equiv C$ is a simple function

Comment: What if simple functions can only have finite support?

Comment: The Stanford website doesn't say that simple functions aren't dense. It says that step functions are not dense. There are simple functions which aren't step functions.

Comment: @DoctorWho But you can always approximate Lebesgue measurable sets with rectangles.

Comment: @user808843 "Approximate" in what sense? What you really mean is that one can approximate the characteristic function of a Lebesgue measurable set with the characteristic functions of rectangles. But this approximation fails when working with the $L^\infty$ norm.

Comment: @DoctorWho Thanks for the clarification. Now it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

If $|f(x)| \leq M$ a.e. and $f_n(x)=\sum_i \frac i n I_{E_i}$ where $E_{i}=f^{-1} [\frac {i-1}n , \frac  i n)$ then $f_n$ is a simple function and $\|f_n-f||_{\infty}\leq \frac  1n$. Note that the sum in the definition of $f_n$ is actually a finite sum.